# Is there any way to run SOAP requests?

Tags: r, soap, xsd, tls1.2, rcurl

I have been using [RCurl and SSOAP](https://github.com/omegahat/) packages to run SOAP requests in R but, recently, after an upgrade to TLSv1.2 from the service providers' side they stopped working.

See, for example, the below:

```
library(RCurl)

getURL('https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/bootstrap-static', ssl.verifyhost=FALSE, ssl.verifypeer=FALSE)
```

Gives this error:

> ```
> Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
>   error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
> ```

When trying to connect to a different server I am getting the below:

> ```
> Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
>   Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to ##########
> ```

I am able to workaround the 'getURL' issue using the httr-package but I haven't found an alternative for passing arguments and calling functions through SSOAP.